# What is contained inside a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, json, variables

I have looked a bit into json and I wondered if I store a json path(for example: `foo.bar`) inside a variable and call that variable then what am I actually calling, is it `foo.bar` or is it whatever that `foo.bar` contains?

**Edit:**
I will show a example:

```
var json = { "foo": { "bar": "some value" } };
var container = json.foo.bar;
document.write(contaier);
//Is that equals document.write(json.foo.bar);
//Or is it equals document.write("some value");
//I know that in this particular example this doesn’t make any use, but if you whant to manipulate the path it does.
```

Comment: Wut? A code sample would be helpful here. Variables cannot be "called".

Comment: Its very unclear and seems poetic

Comment: OK, got a code sample now. Question still doesn't make any more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has the same effect as `document.write("some value");`.

The value stored in the variable is a copy of the value in the property. In this case it's a string, so the variable contains a copy of the reference to the string.

If you change the content of the object (which is not JSON by the way, it's a Javascript object) after getting the value into the variable, the value in the variable stays unchanged:

```
var obj = { "foo": { "bar": "some value" } };
var container = obj.foo.bar;
obj.foo.bar = "some other value";
document.write(container); // shows "some value"
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON can't serialize functions. So `foo.bar` can never be a function. Calling it will give you an Error.

If you're asking about **pass-by-value** vs **pass-by-reference**: If `foo.bar` is an Object you'll get a *reference*. If it's a scalar (like a number or a string) you'll get the *value*.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain this to you by showing you some simple lines of code:

```
var data = {
    foo: {
        bar: 'case 1'
    },
    'foo.bar': 'case 2'
};

console.log(data.foo.bar); // 'case 1'
console.log(data['foo.bar']); // 'case 2'
console.log(data['foo']['bar']); // 'case 1'
```

### Case 1

In the first case you have a property `foo` which contains an object with the property `bar` containing the String `case 1`.

### Case 2

In the second case you have a property called `foo.bar` containing the string `case 2`

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = { "foo": { "bar": "some value" } };
```

Here you assign the value `{ "foo": { "bar": "some value" } }`, which is an *object literal*, to `json`.

```
var container = json.foo.bar;
```

Here you assign the value of the `bar` property of the `foo` property of `json` to `container`. It works like any other variable assignment, you assign the *value* of the expression on the right to the variable on the left. And that value is `"some value"`.